# How to make Google Sheets auto update my macros after adding row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

**Problem**:
After adding a row in my Google Sheet my existing macros stop working because the cells they refer to are now shifted one row.

**Question**:
Is there a way to make Google Sheets auto update my macros just like it updates all the functions in the sheet?

Comment: Sure, it is possible, but how to implement it depends on which rows you are interested in (first row, last row, a row with a certain reference to the first / last row).  To tell you how to do it in your specific case I would need to see your current code.

Comment: @ziganotschka This is my cell referencing code: var factor = spreadsheet.getRange('O4');
When I add a row at the top of the sheet the macro should be updated to range O5.

Comment: Do you add the row manually or with a script?

Comment: @ziganotschka manually.

Answer (score 1):

### Use `PropertiesService` and `onChange` trigger

- [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) allows you to store a variable (like  the row of interest) between script runs
- The [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `onChange` fires automatically when a change (such as row insertion) has taken place
- You can set-up the latter to modify the row of interest if another row has been inserted above

Sample:

```
var sheetToWatch = "Sheet1";

function setUp(){  
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("row", 4);
}

function onChange(e) {
  var row = parseInt(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("row"));
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  Logger.log(e.changeType);
  Logger.log(sheet.getName());
  Logger.log(sheetToWatch);
  Logger.log(sheet.getActiveRange().getRow());
  if (e.changeType == "INSERT_ROW"  &&  sheet.getName() == sheetToWatch && sheet.getActiveRange().getRow()<=row){
    row++;
  }
}


function withRow(){
  var row = parseInt(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("row"));
  // do something with my row
}
```

Instructions:

- Run `fucntion setUp()` once to set the initial row
- If rows above this row will be inserted, `onChange()` will change the var `row` automatically (do not forget to bind an installable trigger to `onChange()` )
- Run your own function (called here `withRow()`) and retrieve the actual `row` from `ScripProperties`